# having trouble with referencing project name that include hyphen when using bq command-line tool

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that generates rows for insertion into a table.  The query references tables in different projects.  The project names include hyphen (ex. abc-xyz).   When I try to use bq command and use ` to enclose the project name I get error and if I don't I get error and if I try single or double quotes or brackets still get error.  Is there a way to reference another project that has hyphen in its name in a query using bq command?

Here is what I get when I run a sample command:

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "select account_id, max(updated) max_updated, max(_PARTITIONTIME) max_pt from `abc-xyz`.myset.mytable group by 1"

-bash: abc-xyz: command not found

When I copy and paste that same query strin in the UI, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: What is the command that you are trying to run?

Comment: I added the command I was running to the post

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should enclose whole table reference into back-ticks - not just project itself

So, instead of

```
`abc-xyz`.myset.mytable
```

try

```
`abc-xyz.myset.mytable`
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Tried it and the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mikhail's suggestion, if you have content in your query that conflicts with Bash syntax (such as quotes and dollar signs), another approach is to put your query in a file, e.g. `my_query.sql`, and then run:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < my_query.sql
```

This will pipe the unmodified contents of the file to the `bq` tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem with that approach is that we have a series of (sql) commands that need to be executed and it might include some other commands (like loading a file using API call).  We need to see all the processing/commands that happen for one job in one place, not spread out in files.